# Is there any way to customize eclipse diff viewer like netbeans?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

[image: How can i customize my eclipse diff viewer like this or any other plugin available for netbeans]

Image 1 : Netbeans .
Image 2 : Eclipse .

[image: I]

Answer (score 1):

This *on the fly* diff can be configured on eclipse, just do as the following image
I agree is not as good as in Netbeans, but is quite simmilar
[image: Quick Diff Config]

Answer (score 0):

Look at Preferences -> General -> Compare/Patch, and there is also a link on that page to Colors and Fonts. So there is quite a lot of customization possible, but I'm not sure how close it will get you to Netbeans.

Comment: Hi Francis , I already changed the eclipse diff preferences but it has no change . Did I miss anything ? . Please visit the link https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B_IaKNX7vOzaSjhXTXJDbXBzRkk/edit